# Displaying a product price on Ad Push content?

Tags: commerce

Hi just started using Drupal a couple of days ago. 
I'm using Commerce Kickstart 2. I'm having troubles displaying the product price on the Ad Push content. I just want to know if there is a way to display the product price on the Ad Push?

[image: This is what I wanted to do]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a new Product Reference field to the Ad Push content type. This allows content editors to pick a product to reference. You can then display the price through the "manage display" tab of the Ad Push form. You'll want the "Product: Price" field.